# Proper time elapsed along a worldline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravitational-waves, geodesics

> The question is about the following metric describing the gravitational wave propagating along the $z$ direction:
>   $$ds^2=-dt^2+(1+h(t,z))dx^2+(1-h(t,z))dy^2+dz^2$$
>   where $$h(t,z)=H\cos{k}(t-z).$$ $h$ is small and hence one can ignore quadratic and higher powers of $H$.
>
> Consider the worldline of two massive particles, A and B at fixed spatial coordinates. They have the same y and z coordinates and their x coordinates differ by $L>0: x_b=x_A+L$, A photon is emitted by A at a coordinate time $t = t_e$, reaches B and is immediately reflected back to A where it is detected. Show that the proper time $τ_{ABA}(t_e)$ – the Round Trip duration – that elapses along A′s worldline between emission and detection of the photon is given by:
>   $$τ_{ABA}(t_e)=2L+\frac{H}{k}\cos{k}(L+t_e)\sin{k}L.$$

**Attempt at solution**

For A and B they have $dx=dy=dz=0$ Therefore the proper time along A is given by the elapsed coordinate time $\Delta{t_A}$ along A.

We need to use the metric to relate the physical time taken for the photon to reach B. For the photon $d\tau=0$ so $dt^2=(1+h(t,z))dx^2$.
What I am not sure now is what to substitute for $z$, is $z=0$ all the time or because the propagation is along x I need to use $h(t,x)$ instead. My next step will be to solve the differential equation for dt to compute the coordinate time taken for the photon to travel from $x_A$ to $x_B$

Comment: Step 1: buy trout, step 2: slap however set this question. Of course, the answer will depend on $z$. To get the provided answer take $z=0$

Comment: But if I take z=0 I don't see how L comes to play in the formula for h, i.e $\cos{k}(L+t_e)$

Comment: Note that while the gravitational wave is propagating in the $z$ direction, the photon is travelling back and forth in the $x$ direction!